# Derivative of magnitude of complex trace (function of matrices with Gateaux derivative)

Tags: linear-algebra, gateaux-derivative

So if I define $y(U)=|Tr(U^*V)|^2$

If I do the Gateaux derivative:

$y_U[\tilde{U}] =\frac{d}{d\epsilon}|Tr((U^*+\epsilon\tilde{U})V)|^2
$,

Here is where I get confused because of how things are nested - the trace has a real and imaginary part and I'm not sure how to handle this

My intuition says that the derivative is like
$y_U[\tilde{U}] = 2Tr(V^*)$ with the variation somewhere in here, but I can't figure out how to get that if it should be the case. Some tips would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y(U) = \overline{\operatorname{tr} (U^*V)} \operatorname{tr} (U^*V)$.

\begin{eqnarray}
y(U+tH) -y(U) &=& \overline{\operatorname{tr} ((U+tH)^*V)} \operatorname{tr} ((U+tH)^*V) - \overline{\operatorname{tr} (U^*V)} \operatorname{tr} (U^*V) \\
&=& (\overline{\operatorname{tr} (U^*V)}  + t\overline{\operatorname{tr}(H^*V)} ) ( \operatorname{tr} (U^*V) + t\operatorname{tr} (H^*V) ) - \overline{\operatorname{tr} (U^*V)} \operatorname{tr} (U^*V) \\
&=& 2 t \operatorname{re} ( \overline{\operatorname{tr} (U^*V)} \operatorname{tr} (H^*V) ) + O(t^2)
\end{eqnarray}

Hence $d y(U,H) = 2 \operatorname{re} ( \overline{\operatorname{tr} (U^*V)} \operatorname{tr} (H^*V) ) $.

Note that there are many different notations for the Gateaux derivative.

Note, if $H$ is real, with $\operatorname{tr} (U^*V) = a+ib$ and
$V= V_r+i V_i$
then $d y(U,H) = 2 \operatorname{re} ( (a-ib) (  \operatorname{tr} (V_i^TH) -i \operatorname{tr} (V_r^TH)) = 2 \operatorname{tr}((aV_r-bV_i)^T H)$, and similarly,
$d y(U,iH) = 2 \operatorname{re} ( (a-ib) (  \operatorname{tr} (V_i^TH) -i \operatorname{tr} (V_r^TH)) = 2 \operatorname{tr}((bV_r+aV_i)^T H)$

Comment: Thanks copper, is $\frac{dy}{dU}$ sitting here somewhere? For a scalar variation I would expect like $\frac{dy}{du}H$, so I could just see what the derivative/gradient was. In this case where the variation is a matrix. something is different that I can't put my finger on. I'm really after $\frac{dy}{dU}$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by derivative, $y$ is a map from a complex space into the reals, so it cannot have a (Frechet) derivative in the usual sense.

Comment: If I have $U = u+iv$, does $\frac{dy}{du}$ and $\frac{dy}{dv}$ make sense in terms of Frechet?

Comment: Yes, then the $H$ above would be purely real or purely imaginary and the resulting map is Frechet differentiable.

Comment: The idea behind the derivative is that $Df(x)h$ is an approximation to $f(x+h)-f(x)$, and if $h$ can be imaginary when $f$ is real then it makes no sense (unless zero, but who cares about that).

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me get my head straight on this!